# What are the permissions necessary for an 'Always-On-Display' app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make an **AOD (always on display)** app using `Flutter`.
I just want to know what are the `permissions that my app requires in order to be functional`.
I didn't start the proj. yet, therefore I don't even have any code to share.
Would start the proj. after I get my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Always on display,you can achieve it by using this package

https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

you can easily call like this and achieve your goal.like follows

```
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
// ...

// The following line will enable the Android and iOS wakelock.
Wakelock.enable();

// The next line disables the wakelock again.
Wakelock.disable();
```